# Set WM_WINDOW_ROLE property to an arbitrary window?

Tags: linux, x11

I'm trying to make named scratchpad in xmonad, and I need some way to find/distinct windows. For example nvim-gtk. I can't use WM_NAME because name is changeable by nvim-gtk. So, I'm trying to set role property and find the window by that property. I'm able to set role for example to gvim (gvim --role Notes) but I failed to do the same with another applications.. That is my problem. Does anybody know how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Answered in a now-deleted comment:

```
xprop -id "$windowid" -format WM_WINDOW_ROLE 8s -set WM_WINDOW_ROLE "$role"
```